# Trouble using temp table in where clause

Tags: sql

I'm creating a report where the user can select between 2 statuses of a field. The default `Completed` status and `Any`. If the selected status is not `Completed`, then it needs to ignore or select all values. I created a temp table with all of the distinct values and set it to a local variable. I'm trying to use a `case statement` and this temp table in my `where` clause to handle this, but it's not letting me. Is there a better way to handle this other than setting the `sql` as a string and `exec'ing` it?

```
Declare @paramCompleted varchar(20) = 'Completed'
Declare @paramCommitmentExamined varchar(20) = 'Requested'
Declare @paramDateFrom Date
Declare @paramDateTo Date

Declare @PurchStatus as table([status] varchar(15))
insert into @PurchStatus([status]) select DISTINCT TX01STAT from dimFile_T order by TX01STAT
--select * from @PurchStatus
SELECT 
    dbo.ParseDate(O.ORDDATE) AS ORDDATE,
    T.TX04STAT,--Commitment Examined & type
    E.EXAMINER,
    T.TX02STAT,--Outside search
    C.COUNTY,
    S.SETTSTAT,
    CASE
        WHEN L.LOANAMT = 0 THEN 'Cash'
        ELSE CAST(L.LOANAMT AS VARCHAR(10))
    END AS LOANAMT,
    T.TX01STAT,--Purchase agreement received
    M.MKTSOURC,
    CASE 
        WHEN C.FIRMFILE LIKE '%PC%' THEN 'Commercial'
        WHEN C.FIRMFILE LIKE '%RC%' THEN 'Commercial'
        ELSE 'Residential'
    END AS FIRMFILE,
    C.FIRMFILE as FILENUM,
    'Metes & Bounds' AS LOTUNIT,
    S.STATCMT
FROM
    dimFile_O O
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_T T ON T.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_E E ON E.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_C C ON C.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_S S ON S.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_L L ON L.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_M M ON M.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
    LEFT JOIN dimfile_P P ON P.FIRMFILE = O.FIRMFILE
WHERE
    T.TX04STAT IN (@paramCommitmentExamined)
    AND T.TX01STAT IN (
        CASE
            WHEN @paramCompleted = 'Completed' THEN @paramCompleted
            ELSE @PurchStatus
        END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `select`.  But, I think the `in` could also be improved:

```
WHERE T.TX04STAT =  @paramCommitmentExamined AND
      ((@paramCompleted = 'Completed' AND T.TX01STAT = @paramCompleted) OR
       (coalesce(@paramCompleted, '') <> 'Completed' AND T.TX01STAT IN (SELECT status FROM @PurchStatus))
      )
```

Don't use `in` with string variables.  You'll start to think that `in ('Completed,Requested')` checks for two values rather than one.

Comment: I hadnt thought of grouping them like that. Works perfectly. Thanks!